# how to use transaction across service in nestjs with typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

How can I have a transaction across different service in my project?
I try my code as below but the transaction doesn't rollback while exception threw.
[image]

The following code will rollback as expected, but I would like to separate the create logic into corresponding service.
[image]

```
public async createProduct(dto: CreateProductDto): Promise<ProductEntity> {
  const product = await this.dataSource.transaction(async (entityManager) => {
    dto.price = await this.priceService.createPrice(
      entityManager,
      dto.unitPrice,
    );
    throw new BadRequestException('bad');
    return await entityManager
      .getRepository(ProductEntity)
      .create({ ...dto })
      .save();
  });
  console.log(product);

  return product;
}
```

Comment: Try to add `await` keyword before `this.dataSource.transaction` in your first code snippet. (as the second). Your approach should work perfectly, if you always pass the `entityManager` object generated by `transaction`

Comment: I tried but it still commit the createPrice action instead of rollback :(

Comment: Please add your exact code by inserting it in markdown, (not with picture)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone, I just found the problem is I can't chain the save() right after create() which will call the entity's save() fn instead of the entityManager's one, and start a new transaction.

```
async createPrice(dto, entityManager){
  //wrong code
  return entityManager.create(PriceEntity, {...}).save();

  //works
  const price = entityManager.create(PriceEntity, {...});
  return entityManager.save(price);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add **@Transactional()** decorator before insert function from your services [typeorm transaction](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions?q=transactional)/
[typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked)

```
@Transactional()
public async createProduct(...) {
...
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer but the decorator was removed since v0.3.0 and I am using v0.3.6
"TransactionRepository, TransactionManager, Transaction decorators were completely removed. These decorators do the things out of the TypeORM scope."
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: hi @CTC you can try [typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked](https://github.com/odavid/typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked)

Comment: the thing is that currently default ConnectionManager is no longer in use in TypeOrm. In the past I did happily use `typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked` ...

Comment: `typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked` was superseded with [`typeorm-transactional`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-transactional), which uses AsyncLocalStorage and is compatible with the latest TypeORM release.